# Python - I need to rearrange a character of a string element in a list

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop

So I have a function that takes a string input and turns it into pig latin.

For all words that begin with consonants (everything except vowels), I have to take the first letter of that word and move it to the back and then add "ay" to the word.

For example "like" would become "ikelay".

In my program, the string input given to me is first split and then each element of that newly created list is checked to see if the first character of that element is either a vowel, a consonant, or otherwise.

```
def simple_pig_latin(input, sep=" ", end="."):
    splitinput = input.split(sep)
    for i in splitinput:
        if splitinput[splitinput.index(i)][0] in ['a','e','i','o','u']:
            splitinput[splitinput.index(i)] = str(i) + "way"
        elif splitinput[splitinput.index(i)][0] in ['b','c','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','m','n','p','q','r','s','t','v','w','x','y','z']:
            splitinput[splitinput.index(i)] = str(i) + "ay"
        else:
            continue
    finalstring = ' '.join(splitinput)
    finalstring = finalstring + end


simple_pig_latin("i like this")
```

Notice in the elif branch, I am supposed to take the first letter of i and put it at the end of that word and add "ay" to it. Given the input string "i like this" **I should turn the second word (since like starts with l, making it a consonant) into 'ikelay'** How would I rearrange like so that it became ikel?

Comment: Why are you doing `splitinput[splitinput.index(i)]`? I recommend doing a search and looking at some of the _many_ examples of Pig Latin programs on Stack Overflow. Also, don't use `input` as a variable name: that shadows the built-in `input` function.

Comment: alot of the other pig latin programs on here use things I havent learned yet or things that aren't allowed in this assignment. Regarding the use of "input" that was not my decision. The assignment forces us to call that parameter input.

Comment: Use `for i, text in enumerate(splitinput)` if you iterate over a list and want to alter that list by keeping an index into the list.

Comment: Try `str(text[1:]) + text[0] + "ay"`.

Comment: @Evert Could you explain what [1:] is doing? I know it has to do with slicing but I'm a little rusty.

Comment: Try printing text[1:]; best way to see what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to keep your structure while still removing the useless code :

```
def simple_pig_latin(input_text, sep=" ", end="."):
    words = input_text.split(sep)
    new_words = []
    for word in words:
        if word[0].lower() in ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']:
            new_words.append(word + "way")
        else:
            new_words.append(word[1:] + word[0] + "ay")
    finalstring = sep.join(new_words)
    finalstring = finalstring + end
    return finalstring


print simple_pig_latin("i like this")
# iway ikelay histay.
```

Notes :

- Your function needs to return something
- It's probably easier to create a new list than to mutate the original one
- if `i` is already a string, there's no need to call `str(i)`
- `i` is usually used for an integer between `0` and `n-1`. Not for words.
- `word[0]` is the first letter of your word
- `word[k:]` is `word` without the first `k` letters
- to simplify your code, I consider that if the first letter isn't a vowel, it must be a consonant.
- I call `lower()` on the first letter in order to check if `'I'` is a vowel.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! And yes the function wasn't returning anything because it was still a wip.

Comment: Um One more thing, How would I modify the code to read sep as a parameter? For example, simple_pig_latin(input, sep='-') would simply split all characters before and after the dash. I currently have sep equal to a space but how would I change it so that it would read sep from the given input? I am getting a "'function' object has no attribute 'split'" error when I set sep equal to none so that it can be filled in by whatever input is given.

Answer (score 1):

For your question, you could change your code `str(i) + "ay"` to `i[1:] + i[0] + "ay"` in your `elif` branch.